# Swift Package Manager target linking

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I want to be able to import just 1 target/package from a Swift Package. To do that, I have the following structure:

```
TopLevelDirectory
  |- Package.swift
  |- Sources
       |- MyTargetName
             |- main.swift
             |- SubFolder1
                 |- Swifty1.swift
             |- SubFolder2
                 |- Swifty2.swift
  |- Tests
       |- MyTargetNameTests
             |- SubFolder1Tests
                 |- Swifty1Tests.swift
             |- SubFolder2Tests
                 |- Swifty2Tests.swift
       |- LinuxMain.swift
```

Now, when I run `swift build` and `swift run`, this compiles and runs just fine. However, when I run `swift test`, I get linker errors to content in `Swifty1.swift` and `Swifty2.swift`.

Now, in my test file, I have the line `@testable import MyTargetName` to try to import the target

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Package.swift:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackageName",
    platforms: [
      .macOS(.v10_15), .iOS(.v10)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyPackageName", targets: ["MyTargetName"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyTargetName", dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(name: "MyTargetNameTests", dependencies: ["MyTargetName"])
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out my own problem. Under `MyTargetName`, I had a main.swift file. When building and running, it saw the executable and didn't have a problem. But when running `swift test`, it didn't know what to do with the executable and threw a linker error. Why? I have no idea